# Mocking void method with MOQ linq to mocks functional syntax

Tags: linq, mocking, moq

I like the functional syntax of MOQ e.g.

```
var mocked = Mock.Of<Interface>(x => x.Method() == methodReturnValue)
```

however I cannot work out how to use this syntax for a void method.
Is there a constant (like It.Is) that is a placeholder for void?

Thanks

Comment: void methods on the interface wont do anything anyway so I am having trouble understanding what the problem is here (at least for the fluent API)

Comment: I'm used to dealing with strict mocks where you have to define all behavior even if it does nothing, it looks like the functional syntax generates loose mocks so you are correct that it isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

@Nkosi answered this with his comment.

All functional syntax mocks are loose by default and therefore you have no need to mock void return functions.